# parsing ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required by MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn

With the following code. First calculate the mid prices from the highest and lowest.

```
high_prices = df.loc[:,'High'].as_matrix()
low_prices = df.loc[:,'Low'].as_matrix()
mid_prices = (high_prices+low_prices)/2.0
```

Now you can split the training data and test data. The training data will be the first 11,000 data points of the time series and rest will be test data.

```
train_data = mid_prices[:11000]
test_data = mid_prices[11000:]
```

Now you `nescaler = MinMaxScaler()` to define a scaler to normalize the data. MinMaxScalar scales all the data to be in the region of 0 and 1. You can also reshape the training and test data to be in the shape `[data_size, num_features]`.
Scale the data to be between 0 and 1 when scaling remember! You normalize both test and train data with respect to training data. Because you are not supposed to have access to test data.

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1,1)
test_data = test_data.reshape(-1,1)
```

Train the Scaler with training data and smooth data.

```
smoothing_window_size = 2500
for di in range(0,10000,smoothing_window_size):
    scaler.fit(train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:])
    train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:] = 
scaler.transform(train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:])
```

You normalize the last bit of remaining data.

```
scaler.fit(train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:])
train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:] = 
scaler.transform(train_data[di+smoothing_window_size:,:])
```

Reshape the data back to the shape of `[data_size]`. Reshape both train and test data

```
train_data = train_data.reshape(-1)
```

Normalize test data.

```
test_data = scaler.transform(test_data).reshape(-1)
```

Now perform exponential moving average smoothing. So the data will have a smoother curve than the original ragged data

```
EMA = 0.0
gamma = 0.1
for ti in range(11000):
  EMA = gamma*train_data[ti] + (1-gamma)*EMA
  train_data[ti] = EMA
```

Used for visualization and test purposes.

```
all_mid_data = np.concatenate([train_data,test_data],axis=0)
```

In other words, you say the prediction at t+1 is the average value of all the stock prices you observed within a window of t to t−N.

```
window_size = 100
N = train_data.size
std_avg_predictions = []
std_avg_x = []
mse_errors = []

for pred_idx in range(window_size,N):

    if pred_idx >= N:
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(k, '%Y-%m-%d').date() + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    else:
        date = df.loc[pred_idx,'Date']

    std_avg_predictions.append(np.mean(train_data[pred_idx-window_size:pred_idx]))
    mse_errors.append((std_avg_predictions[-1]-train_data[pred_idx])**2)
    std_avg_x.append(date)

print('MSE error for standard averaging: %.5f'%(0.5*np.mean(mse_errors)))


plt.figure(figsize = (18,9))
plt.plot(range(df.shape[0]),all_mid_data,color='b',label='True')
plt.plot(range(window_size,N),std_avg_predictions,color='orange',label='Prediction')
plt.xticks(range(0,df.shape[0],50),df['Date'].loc[::50],rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Mid Price')
plt.legend(fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Got some warnigs

```
hp@hp-desktop:~$ python3 predict_stock.py 
Loaded data from the Kaggle repository
predict_stock.py:76: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  high_prices = df.loc[:,'High'].as_matrix()
predict_stock.py:77: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  low_prices = df.loc[:,'Low'].as_matrix()
MSE error for standard averaging: 0.00418
```

but it worked great except date format are unchangeable
While with alphavantage this is the output

```
predict_stock.py:76: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  high_prices = df.loc[:,'High'].as_matrix()
predict_stock.py:77: FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead.
  low_prices = df.loc[:,'Low'].as_matrix()
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:595: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype object was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:595: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype object was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:595: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype object was converted to float64 by MinMaxScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict_stock.py", line 98, in <module>
    scaler.fit(train_data[di:di+smoothing_window_size,:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 334, in fit
    return self.partial_fit(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 362, in partial_fit
    force_all_finite="allow-nan")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 582, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required by MinMaxScaler.
```

The cvs file has been correctly collected first plot with actual data stored, the second plot with prediction and mse are not created.

And there is some issue with the [AAL plot] image: 
[image]

On the image above you can see that the prediction (orange line) stops before data ends. So its seems to be a moved average. And why all inputs stop before the end of date as on the source file (see following)

```
3408,2019-04-12,34.5,35.235,34.69,34.99
3407,2019-04-11,33.91,34.97,34.81,33.99
3406,2019-04-10,33.09,34.13,34.02,33.76
3405,2019-04-09,32.6,33.52,33.31,33.37
3404,2019-04-08,33.44,33.9529,33.88,33.64
3403,2019-04-05,33.88,34.4,34.06,33.97
3402,2019-04-04,33.35,34.12,33.93,33.96
```